# UILabel doesn't change after a gesture action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have some troubles with an app that download the information from a WebService.

I have various UILabel define in the Storyboard, this are connected with IBOutlet, from the start of app I download de info and put in an array, then put the strings in the UILabel in the first loading. The idea is when the user use a gesture like swipe to the left, the text in the UILabel's have to change.

But in my method action when is the gesture of swipe I put that change the text of this UILabel, when I test, the UILabel doesn't change. I just set the text with a string of the array.

I'm doing something wrong? There is another way? This way is not the correct and best practices? Why the text don't change?

---

About the code, here is the complete method action for the swipe gesture, in that part it's suppose to change the text of the UILabel.

```
NSInteger total = [places count];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection direction = [(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender direction];

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 1.0f;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;


    switch (direction) {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
            if (imageIndex==total-1) {
                imageIndex = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                imageIndex++;
            }
            transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
            break;
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
            if (imageIndex==0) {
                imageIndex = total-1;
            }
            else
            {
                imageIndex--;
            }
            transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }




    place = [places objectAtIndex:imageIndex];

    review.text=@"HOLA";//[place objectForKey:@"review"];

    phones.text = [place objectForKey:@"number"];
    directions.text = [place objectForKey:@"directions"];
    mainTitle.text = [place objectForKey:@"name"];

    principalImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[place objectForKey:@"image_url"]]]];
    //self.typeFoodIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[typefoodimages objectAtIndex:imageIndex]];
    mainLogo.image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[place objectForKey:@"logo_url"]]]];
    /*NSString * key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)imageIndex];
    UIAlertView * check = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:[place objectForKey:@"review"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [check show];*/

    [principalImage.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
```

Comment: Please paste some showing how you currently do it

Answer (score 0):

first check that either your control is going to the gesture action or not, mark some break point in that, and it would be better if you provide some code of your current working code

Comment: Actually it's pretty curious because 1 of the UILabel's it's a title, the title change perfect but the other's not

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a common problem with UILabel, because the user interaction is disabled by default for this control. Make sure that you have enabled the userInteraction (by "checking" it in the XIB/storyboard or programmatically setting it. That should start sending gesture events.

Comment: The user interaction mode it's already active, but I'm not going to interact with the user with the UILabel, is static and have to change when the user do a swipe to an UIImageView

Comment: Did you check if you are getting the swipe event? Another common problem of UI not getting updated is because the update is not done on main thread. Not sure if that's the case with you but worth checking it if you are using multiple threads.

Comment: Mmm, that sounds like a solution, but how can I check what you are suggest?

Comment: Put a break point in the block of code where you are doing the swipe/or updating the label and when the breakpoint hits check in the debug navigator (on the left panel in xcode) which thread it's invoked in. It should be main thread.

Comment: It sounds to me that you don't have the connection with the outlet. Did you verify that also?

Comment: I already check the connections with the outlet, but maybe I don't test well enough, what kind of test you think?